# Rendering partial and specific record with id in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, record, partial

I have a model - books. I can render all books with partial <%= render @books %>, where the output from the form is being processed. Then I get all records being printed to the index page. Now I want to print only record from the partial with specific id, let's say show localhost/id/50 on the main page with the use of partial. How can I do it? Do I use "where" function or so... please explain.

Thank you so much,

Comment: What framework and language do you use?

Comment: I use Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

there will be partial views/books/_book.html.erb.
you can use it to show single object data.

```
<%= render 'books/book', @book %>
```

Comment: in same case, you can use <%= render @book %> too

Comment: Where do I add id e.g. 50 of the book, I want to render?

Comment: so, somewhere in the controller, you are getting books(may be as `@books = Book.all`)  you can get the single book as `@book = Book.find(50)`